# Working with Multiple Ranges in a Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a **worksheet named Start Page** which i am working with. The **objective of my code** is to inform the user if a cell is blank , that a value needs to be entered through a **message box**.  I have been able to do it with the use of an **If statement**. See my code below:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Start page").Range("A4")
If rng = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Date from A4", vbOKCancel
    Exit Sub
End If
```

However i trying to **avoid using multiple If statements**. The cells i am referring to and message boxes are below:

```
Sheets(“Start page”).range(“A4”) msgbox “Please enter First valuation Date inA4”

Sheets(“Start page”).range(“F5”) msgbox “ Please enter the BPS”

Sheets(“Start page”).range(“F7”) msgbox “ Please enter Account number”

Sheets(“Start page”).range(“F9”) msgbox “ Please enter Date”

Sheets(“Start page”).range(“F11”)msgbox “ Please enter Number of Periods”

Sheets(“Start page”).range(“F13”)msgbox “Please Enter number of Days in the Year"
```

**Is there an efficient way of doing this ?**

Comment: You can define two arrays, one for the ranges, one for the messages. After that you can loop through them with `For Each`.

Comment: you would still need an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am picturing your sheet.

[image: Set up]

The code will loop through the ranges and the first one it finds empty will pop up a message.

[image: Pop Up Message]

The code uses the cell above in the message.

[image: Cell Above]

```
Sub FndBlnk()
    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range

    Set Rng = Range("A4,F5,F7,F9,F11,F13")

    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        If c <> "" Then
        Else: MsgBox "Enter " & c.Offset(-1)
        c.Select
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```